# "Renaming" a database role

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

For reasons i don't want to elaborate, it has been decided to rename our database roles.
I know there is no simple way to rename a role (no idea why), 
but i came up with this solution:

```
create table #RoleAssignment (id int identity, RoleName varchar(256), UserName varchar(256))
insert into #RoleAssignment
select roles.name as RoleName, users.name as UserName 
  from sys.sysusers as roles
  join sys.database_role_members as members
    on members.role_principal_id = roles.uid
  join sys.sysusers as users
    on users.uid = members.member_principal_id
 where roles.issqlrole = 1
   and roles.name like 'OldRolePrefix_%'

declare @id int = null
declare @RoleName varchar(256)
declare @NewRoleName varchar(256)
declare @UserName varchar(256)

select top 1 @id = id, @RoleName = RoleName, @UserName = UserName,@NewRoleName = replace(RoleName,'OldRolePrefix_','NewRolePrefix_') from #RoleAssignment

while (@id is not null)
begin
    execute sp_executesql N'sp_droprolemember @InSPRoleName, @InSPUserName',N'@InSPRoleName varchar(256), @InSPUserName varchar(256)', @InSPRoleName = @RoleName, @InSPUserName = @UserName 
    execute sp_executesql N'sp_addrolemember @InSPRoleName, @InSPUserName',N'@InSPRoleName varchar(256), @InSPUserName varchar(256)', @InSPRoleName = @NewRoleName, @InSPUserName = @UserName 
    delete from #RoleAssignment where id = @id
    set @id = null
    select top 1 @id = id, @RoleName = RoleName, @UserName = UserName from     #RoleAssignment
end
```

After this ,the scripts are run that set up role permissions.

I tested this and overall it works.
But even after readign and testing out I am not sure:
Did i forgot about anything?

Thank you a lot for any ideas/insights

Comment: I am no expert, so this is just an idea.. in order to make sure you "touched" all the related tables in your script, maybe you can run a Profiler while adding a new role? I think you have an option you can check in order to capture activity on system tables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You didn't specify the version of SQL Server you are using but in SQL Server 2008 and later, you can rename a role with `ALTER ROLE`:

```
ALTER ROLE OldRoleName WITH NAME = NewRoleName;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. HOW did i not see this? Yes, its 2008R2 and later....
Man, this IS embarasing